Backing up multiple user accounts via Time Machine
A Macbook has 2 different user accounts: Mary & Joe
It is my understanding that:

a time machine backup is on a per user basis
a USB backup device must have a dedicated partition for Time Machine data only

Scenario 1: Assume the USB SSD has one APFS partition.  The user account Mary is "time machined" / backed up  to the SSD.   Is there any reason not to backup the Joe account to the same SSD partition?
Scenario 2: Assume that Mary and Joe are on different Macs.   The user account Mary is "time machined" / backed up  to the SSD.   Is there any reason not to backup the Joe account to the same SSD partition?
I ask this question, because it would be nice if I did not have to create a partition for each user to be backed up.  If makes any difference, assume Ventura is the MacOS version.

Where do the user based backup assumption arise? Same with the dedicated partition? Neither rings true to me as something you would be concerned about. When you connect any drive, Time Machine tells you it’s suitable or it offers to erase the drive. Are you over thinking this?


Time Machine backups happen at the system level, not the user level.
Time Machine backups to APFS disks happen at the Volume level, not the Partition level. Volumes are divisions of an APFS Partition.

Scenario one: There is no need to backup the device a second time. The system may even show that it is already backed up from the second user's settings screen.
Scenario two: If have two systems/computers you could create two Volumes in one APFS Partition. The Volumes will share space (unless you set a quota/limit, but be warned these cannot be changed after creating the volume) in the Partition.
Note: Backups to MacOS Extended disks (which don't have Volumes) can share a partition between computers because the Backups folder is subdivided by computer name. There is no reason to do this since the new APFS backup process is faster, and Volumes are easy to create.

AFAIR Time Machine can handle backups from several devices onto one volume/partition (at least it did so in the past).

@nohillside Not for APFS targets, those require volumes. For MacOS Extended, it could because the Backups folder was subdivided by computer.

Ah, thanks for clarifying.

The bit about macOS Extended disks is irrelevant and, in my view, just confuses an otherwise complete answer. (Nevertheless +1)

It does have an impact if the target device is still formatted that way, since the system will allow and supports multiple devices to the same partition in that scenario. It is increasingly irrelevant though, I agree and I welcome edits that reduce confusion
